# 1 htaccess, 2 domains, rewrite to another urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 urls on 1 webpage (1 htaccess), can you help me with permanent redirect (mod_rewrite) 2 subpages on this websites to another urls?

www.something.cz/hello/ -> www.first.cz/#id
 www.something.sk/hello/ -> www.second.sk/someurl/#id

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} something.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?hello/ http://www.first.cz/#id? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} something.sk [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?hello/ http://www.second.sk/someurl/#id? [R=301,L]
```

Report feedback in the comments

Comment: Hello, thank you, but I think it doesn't function :-) nothing happened after replace urls/suburls to real...thank you